# HTML5 Canvas - Certain images are blurry when drawn with context.drawImage()

Tags: javascript, canvas

Certain images are blurry when drawing them onto an HTML5 canvas.

The example below draws two images using context.drawImage(). One of the images is blurry whereas the other looks as expected.

[image: blurry image]

Javascript code to draw the image onto the canvas - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamhickey00/5nte7bjq/16/)

```
function drawImage(canvasId, imageId) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById(imageId);

  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}

// draw blurry example
drawImage('canvas1', 'img1');

// draw non blurry example
drawImage('canvas2', 'img2');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One image is 2969×2105, the other is 100×76.

Comment: You are right. The rainbow image is smaller and won't face the downsampling issues as the larger image. I will read through that answer and get back to you.

Comment: I pasted my image into the downsampling answer - http://jsfiddle.net/adamhickey00/wte7cu0k/1/ 

It still looks blurry using the accepted answer from that question. It does look a little better than my original in comparison.

Comment: I ended up using this library to resize the image with high quality - https://github.com/nodeca/pica